# How can a question be protected before it has been asked?

Tags: support, timestamps, protected-questions, last-activity

[image: Questions list with "5 mins" circled]
[image: Question with "Protected on Jul 31 '14" circled]

I use the Stack Exchange app and came across this by chance. I think that the time shown in the first photo is the time when the question was uploaded. Is this a bug or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: No but the question can only be protected if it was asked in 2014. The question was asked today. :P

Comment: No, it was **active** today.

Comment: I've been confused by the same thing before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are sorting questions by *recent activity*, in which case the last active timestamp in the question list includes the most recent answer, comment or edit.

Although the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878258/uitableviewcell-show-white-background-and-cannot-be-modified-on-ios7) was posted in 2013, a [new answer was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878258/uitableviewcell-show-white-background-and-cannot-be-modified-on-ios7/28250707#28250707) to that question a short while ago, the timestamp reflects the last time that answer was edited.

Comment: Ok thanks. That was my query. Cheers!